# Adding "no results" into search/filter script

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, filter, filtering

yea I know ... another "no results" question ... sorry for that, but i need to ask because i'm fighting with it couple of hours now and preety much nothing works.

I got some script to filter items and I need your help to inject some code to display "no results" message.

```
$("#my-search-input").keyup(function() {
    var search = $(this).val();
    $(".my-list").children().show();
    if (search)
       $(".my-list").children().not(":containsNoCase(" + search + ")").hide();
});


$.expr[":"].containsNoCase = function (el, i, m) {
    var search = m[3];
    if (!search) return false;
       return new RegExp(search,"i").test($(el).text());
};
```

Here's my fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/bk13detv/22/

Basically message should display in every instance of table.

Thanks for your time, cheers.

Comment: are you really need two tables ?

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki Why are you familiar with the project he is working on?

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki yea, actually there is many more ... like 20. Every table is a sort of category and i wrote filter based on select (that's 1st filter -> category) and that input text help users to minimize items in chosen category. More less :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
    $("#my-search-input").keyup(function () {
        var search = $(this).val();
        $(".my-list").children().show();
        $('.noresults').remove();
        if (search) {
            $(".my-list").children().not(":containsNoCase(" + search + ")").hide();
            $(".my-list").each(function () {
                if ($(this).children(':visible').length == 0) 
                    $(this).append('<tr class="noresults"><td colspan="3"><em>No Results</em></td></tr>');
            });

        }
    });
```

See this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bk13detv/26/) for a demo.

Comment: Hi zgood, thank you very much for that code and your time. That's clever solution and i must admit i wasn't even close with mine ;) Your timing is also impresive ;) Cheers.

Comment: Hi @zgood, i don't know if this change something but i've notced small, sort of bug. With tr, td in append method, input did weird loop after search couple of times resulting in displaying an error message with actual items. Unfortunately i can't repeat this issue on fiddle, so maybe my other script interfere here. Anyways when i've changed "tr" to "span" and deleted "td" issue doesn't appear again. Maybe someone will have similiar problem, so yea it's worth a shot. Thanks, cheers.

Comment: Hi @zgood , seems i found that bug i was talking about. My table rows are display none by default (something like accordion) and in your code there is :visible selector. Is there a way to replace that selector with some solution that will work both visible and hidden elements ? (':visible, :hidden') doesn't work. Thanks, cheers.

Comment: @eightythree Yeah, check out this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bk13detv/31/) I made for you. This approach uses a class (`hiddenrow`) to show/hide the rows and will check for that class to display the _No Results_ message. Let me know if this does not work. Thanks

Comment: wow, that's actually work like a charm and seems to be bulletproof solution :) You're a life saver mate, thank you very much for your time and assistance. Have a great weekend, cheers.